# Kafka connect s3 bucket folder

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Can I create my own directory in s3 using confluent S3SinkConnector?

I know it creates a folder structure, unfortunately we need a new directory strcuture.

Comment: Have you tried? What happened? Any errors?

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you want to completely remove the first S3 'folder' ('topics' by default), you can set the `topics.dir` configuration to the backspace character: `\b`.

This way, **{bucket}/`\b`/{partitioner_defined_path}** becomes **{bucket}/{partitioner_defined_path}**.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `topics.dir` followed by the path extracted by the `partitioner.class`.

If you need "a new directory structure" (quoted because S3 has no directories), then you would need to look at implementing your own Partitioner class

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html#s3-object-names